# Problems dynamically adding user controls VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have been set a project from school to design snake in VB.Net but i am struggling to dynamically add the user control which acts as one of the dots in the body of the snake. Every time i add a dot on to the snake the previous vanishes. I assume this is due to me overwriting the previous one by creating a new instance of the object but i cannot find a way of adding a new one in.

```
    Dim body As New Dot
    Sub AddToSnake(ByVal i As Integer)
            'add 1 dot on to the back of the snake
            body.Location = New Point(50 + i, 50)
            body.Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(body)
         End Sub
```

I have tried using body(i) and other ways of adding a new instance of the object but am stuck.
The subroutine will be called up when a new control is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume this is due to me overwriting the previous one by creating a new instance of the object

You aren’t actually creating a new instance anywhere, your code only ever creates a single instance of `Dot` and modifies the single instance’s location in `AddToSnake`. In order to overcome the problem, create a new instance of `Dot` inside `AddToSnake`.

That said, user controls aren’t the correct way for this anyway. You should paint your snake body on a `PictureBox` control, and maintain the body as a a `List(Of Point)`. Then you can simply add new points at the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you, i used the first part you mentioned and the issue resolved. I will try using the second part you mentioned but it doesn't really make sense to me so i will experiment :)